# I cannot get audio to work on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, audio, windows-server-2008

If I remote in Audio is transferred and plays. But if I hook up to the motherboard and log in it does not play. I have all indication it is playing, but neither front or back port is working. I have unplugged the front port and reattached it, but no avail. The rear port is part of the mother board.

Is there a switch I need to turn on in Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the **Windows Audio** service.

- Run `services.msc` and find **Windows Audio**.
- Right click and select **Properties** and set **Startup Type** to **Automatic**.
- Hit **Apply** and then **Start**.

You may need to set the correct audio device under **Control Panel** > **Manage Audio Devices** or **Sound**.

Comment: I've tried both of those Solutions, any other ideas? I've also edited all the reg keys for the Audio Processing objects.